# Can I set the naming style for parameters specifically in local functions?

Tags: resharper

When I'm using local functions in C# I'd like to keep them pure and without being dependent on capturing local variables. Since I can't name my parameters the same as the local variables outside the function, due to name collision, I'd like to prepend them with underscore to have a general working strategy for this.

```
bool MyLocalFunction(string _str)
{
    //...
}

var str = "";

var isValid = MyLocalFunction(str);
```

Is is possible to make ReSharper enforce this naming in all local functions, while not affecting the naming of parameters in regular methods? I can't find that option in the settings.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using C# 8.0 (.NET Core 3.x and .NET Standard 2.1) then you could use [static local functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-8#static-local-functions). For example:

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleAppLocalFunction
{
    public static class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            var first = "Foo";
            var last = "Bar";
            Console.WriteLine(LocalMethod1("Test", "Message"));
            Console.WriteLine(LocalMethod2());

            static string LocalMethod1(string first, string last) => first + last;
            string LocalMethod2() => first + last;
        }
    }
}
```

When you run this the results will be:

`TestMessage`

`FooBar`

The `LocalMethod1` will use the parameters and doesn't have access to the local variables, `LocalMethod2` will use the local variables.

I don't think you can configure ReSharper to use a naming style for local method parameters.

Comment: Thanks, I'm stuck with C#7 for the time being though.

Comment: Sorry to hear that, you could just use standard non-local functions then.